# Process Python not running on ob-ipython

Tags: ipython

I think I must be missing something silly. I am trying to use `ob-ipython` in my `org-mode` files.

When I press `C-c C-c` I get `Process Python not running`.

Do I need to startup some process or something before I can use the installation? I have followed the directions as best as I could and double checked my steps.

Comment: After installing IPython3 I have got the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

I got the similar error, and I fixed it by adding `python` executable (symlinked to `python3`) on `PATH`.

If you look at source, you can see that function [ob-ipython--launch-driver](https://github.com/gregsexton/ob-ipython/blob/950dbde87947f9e8f53f521d4bcf239f3be8ef71/ob-ipython.el#L158) expect `python.exe` or `python` on `PATH` in order to create process.